# Can't open an application Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, icons, linux-headers

I can't open any application at my side panel. Only with Terminal.

For example, I've downloaded a PHPStorm, so I must open a terminal and then:

```
cd ~/Desktop/helper/PhpStorm-2020.1/PhpStorm-201.6668.153/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

And only after it's gonna start.

If I want to click on the icon at side panel nothing to happen

Comment: It might seem like the Ubuntu Dock Gnome extension might not be working. Try enable and disable the extension or try a different dock (eg. Dash to Dock).

Comment: It just shows a side panel. I've understood that I have this problem with applications that were installed with 'SNAP'. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Also, I have a problem with Postman, I can open the net way:                     SNAP=true /snap/postman/current/usr/share/Postman/Postman